# Testing connectionTimeout threshold using Mongo Java driver 3.0.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, connection-timeout, mongo-java-driver

```
Mongo m = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(server , port), creds, MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(2000).socketTimeout(2000).serverSelectionTimeout(10000).socketKeepAlive(true).build());
```

I want to test `connectionTimeOut` to a standalone server. Every time I define the wrong port for a client or stop the server, it fails on the select server step and returns a `serverSelectionTimeOut`. How can I test the `connectionTimeOut` threshold in a development environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are connecting to an existing server (hostname and port), because the connection is setup after the server-selection process. If server selection fails it won't go to the connection-setup step.

If there is no Mongo server that is always available for testing, try deploying an [embedded Mongo server](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) on the fly on your local machine instead. You could write a unit test that automatically launches the embedded Mongo at the start of the test (as is demonstrated [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb)).
Alternatively you could use [MongoUnit](https://mongounit.org) for testing, but I have no experience with that myself.

Once you have a proper server you can force a connectionTimeout, by setting the timeout value to 1 millisecond. You can do that in code

```
MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(1)
```

or by adding a setting to your database-url

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/your_database?connectTimeoutMS=1
```